# Where is the function for add.period in apacite?

Tags: bibtex, apacite

Where is the function for add.period  in `apacite`?. I checked apacite.bst, but didn't find any function for `add.period`. but it is used throughout the bst. Where did it came from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to note that it's not `add.period`, but `add.period$`. The final `$` indicates that it's a BibTeX built-in function. 
Page 33 of [Tame the BeaST](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf) (`texdoc tamethebeast`) explains `add.period$`:

> [image: <code>add.period$</code> -> adds a period at the end of string , except if already ends with a period, or an exclamation or question mark (after removing right braces)]

where  is a string.

And, if you're interested in the implementation:

> [image]

Comment: Got it!. Didn't find this PDF . I checked with `texdoc bibtex`. But Gotta another PDF :)

Comment: @TVMBoy `texdoc bibtex` brings up the BibTeX documentation, which is more of a utilisation guide. The reference to BibTeX programming, in my opinion, is Tame the BeaST (`texdoc tamethebeast`).

Comment: Yeh!. Got it!. thanks

Comment: [`btxhak`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxhak.pdf) also documents the built-ins, but the list in `tamethebeast` might be more convenient.